# Starting a windows service with net.exe without showing the console window

Tags: windows, services, uac, console, elevated

I want to start a service silently with the net.exe command from a non elevated bat file. But I only want the UAC prompt to be asked for the net.exe and after that I don't want the console window to appear.
I know there is a way to hide the console window with a lot of programs like nircmd:

```
nircmd elevatecmd execmd net start [service]
```

But the UAC prompt will be asked for the nircmd program.

Is it possible?

Comment: Any time you elevate a command, the UAC will be displayed. The UAC is being displayed for `nircmd` so it can run `net start` with the proper elevated privileges (which are required by Windows).

Comment: if you read my question you'll see that what I want is that the UAC being asked for the net.exe program, not another program like nircmd, and after that I want the console window to be hidden.

Answer (score 0):

> I only want the UAC prompt to be asked for the net.exe[.] Is it possible?

To the best of my knowledge, the answer is likely "No".

The UAC is being displayed for `nircmd` so it can run `net start` with the proper elevated privileges (which are required by Windows). This elevation must occur before `net start` is run. In my experience, this is generally true of many third-party programs or scripts that perform a similar function.

[Elevate](https://www.winability.com/info/elevate/) is an exception (i.e. it will display `Net Command` in the UAC), but then again, it doesn't suppress the console window like `nircmd` does.

> After that I don't want the console window to appear.

Though a console window might appear with other solutions (e.g. `elevate.exe`, a `.vbs` script), a new console window does not appear after running `nircmd elevatecmd execmd net start example_service`.

**Suppressing The Console Window**

While it likely isn't possible to display `net.exe` in the UAC, you can suppress the console window for the batch file (which it honestly sounds like is your true goal, if I am not misreading things too badly):

1. Create a `.bat` file e.g. `start_service.bat` with something like the following:

   ```
   C:\path\to\nircmd.exe elevatecmd execmd net start example_service
   ```
2. Create a new shortcut somewhere to run this `.bat` file.  Make the target similar to the following:

   ```
   C:\path\to\nircmd.exe execmd C:\path\to\start_service.bat
   ```

For this example, when this shortcut is used (not the `.bat` file directly), only the UAC prompt will be displayed (no console window will appear).

Comment: if you run from a non elevated console "net start service" the UAC will be displayed for the net.exe command. Maybe the way to go is running net.exe from the SYSTEM user in a scheduled task? WHat I do not like of nircmd is that it is not signed.

Comment: sorry, what I was trying to say is that if you elevate net.exe from a nonelevated console (using nircmd.exe, elevate.exe, vbscript...) the UAC will be displayed for the net.exe.

Comment: If you run `net start service` from a non-elevated console, no UAC will be displayed at all, it will simply return an `Access Denied` message. If you elevate `net.exe` from a non-elevated console using `nircmd.exe`, the UAC prompt will be for `nircmd`. Regarding `.vbs`, the scripts I am familiar with do not prompt for `net.exe` either. Using `elevate.exe`, you are correct in that it will display `Net Command` (for the `net.exe`) but it does not suppress the console window, unfortunately.

Comment: I couldn't comment much on the task scheduler solution. Obviously you could give it a shot. That said, while I understand the hesitancy regarding `nircmd` being unsigned, it is a perfectly safe piece of software in my experience.

Comment: With 'nircmd elevate net start service' UAC will be prompted for the net.exe command. As far as I know, nircmd is safe but not everybody knows that, and it will be better that in 2018 would be a signed program. Anyway, thanks for your help.

Comment: Signing is definitely a good idea. And you are welcome. =)

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a way to start and stop a service silently without showing the console window, and UAC displayed for a Microsoft signed program (wscript.exe), with  VBScript that uses WMI to start and stop a service.

**Start a service:**
Create a file StartService.vbs with this code and change the first line with the service you want to start.

```
strServiceName = "YourServiceName"

If Not WScript.Arguments.Named.Exists("elevate") Then
  CreateObject("Shell.Application").ShellExecute WScript.FullName _
    , """" & WScript.ScriptFullName & """ /elevate", "", "runas", 1
  WScript.Quit
End If

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")
Set colListOfServices = objWMIService.ExecQuery ("Select * from Win32_Service Where Name ='" & strServiceName & "'")
For Each objService in colListOfServices
objService.StartService()
Next
```

to start the service:

```
wscript pathto\StartService.vbs
```

**Stop a service:**
Create a file StopService.vbs with the code:

```
strServiceName = "YourServiceName"

If Not WScript.Arguments.Named.Exists("elevate") Then
  CreateObject("Shell.Application").ShellExecute WScript.FullName _
    , """" & WScript.ScriptFullName & """ /elevate", "", "runas", 1
  WScript.Quit
End If

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")
Set colListOfServices = objWMIService.ExecQuery ("Select * from Win32_Service Where Name ='" & strServiceName & "'")
For Each objService in colListOfServices
objService.StopService()
Next
```

to stop the service:

```
wscript pathto\StopService.vbs
```